# Identifying Spikes Values in list - Python

Tags: python, xml, math

The main idea is to identify the "Spikes" from an list, then removing them.

The list below is one random example. The original lists and its values are different and has thousands of data points. Well I know how to remove them by its value but the trick is, when execute the script and there's no spike values, I still remove some valid data that I don't want to.

What I'm trying to do is to move the spikes to a list_spikes then by it's value i can remove from the original_list.

**List**

```
list = [38093376.839, 39272981.98, 213503333390000.0, 39588858.848, 40645622.873,
        40737355.043, 41013379.467, 213503333390.0, 41350199.871, 41924195.171, 
        42279196.003, 43385639.711, 45001378.229, 45935530.445, 46138334.072,
        47901976.55, 49764532.651, 50850625.023, 52298939.613, 53397000.666,
        54327061.668, 55083343.271, 56661356.466, 60457106.969, 213503284490000.0]
```

**Code**

```
list_spikes = []

max_value_list = (max(list))
max_value_list_stdev = (statistics.stdev(list))
for i in list:
   t = max_value_list_stdev * 100 / max_value_list  # stdev percentage of the maximum val
   if i > t:
      list_spikes.append(i)
```

**Desired Output**

```
# list_spikes
[213503333390000.0, 213503284490000.0, 213503333390.0]
```

I just want a general way of doing it with some math, and no "Magical number Threshold".

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: The best and the closeest one I can get is with: `main.cut_off = (main.stdev_value * 2) + main.mean`

Comment: With this I get the spike, but when I dont have spikes it also gives me values..

Comment: I have been scratching my head for 1 week with this..

Comment: Also, I've tried with some % stdev value from the maximum value on the list, if the stdev is at least 10% of the maximum also I consider it a spike, but I think this way of thinking is wrong, because I got values even if I don't have spikes in the list.

Comment: What you want to do is called [anomaly detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomaly_detection) and there are a bunch of ways it can be done. You should be able to find a library that does it for you once you decide what approach to take. Slight aside: you shouldn't use python keywords like `list` as variable names because then they can't be used as a keyword and this can cause weird and unexpected errors.

Comment: As was mentioned earlier, there are a lot of ways you can do this. An easy way might be to compute the z-score (z = (x-mean(x))/std) of each point and if it's absolute value is larger than say 5 you count it as a spike. This z threshold might seem like a "magic number" but it directly tells you how anomalous something has to be for you to consider it a spike. If you check |z|>2 that means about 5% unusual. |z|>3 about 0.3% unusual etc. These spikes are very large so you could do |z|>5 or >10 and probably be just fine

Comment: how xml is related?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi , Thanks but I want a clean pythonic way, about, the list keywork, I agree with you if a use the keyword "alone", but keep in mind that I put it here to simplify the example.

Comment: @g23 Well, I'll try the z score and then I share the results with you

Comment: @balderman The xml is a rrdtool dump, and I've had parsed the xml the get the values, the row values are in Scientific Notation format, the list above is an conversion to fload.

Comment: @g23 Thanks for your help, for now the z score is working like a charm, I need to do some tweks but is 90% done, I can't upvout your cause it is blocked I miss click twice..

Answer (score 1):

Solved with:

(z = (x-mean(x))/std)

shout-out to @g23